# How to get mounted nfs device from a path in Python

Tags: python, nfs

How can I find the host for a nfs share from a file path in Python?

For example, if `df -h` gives:

```
Filesystem              Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdb3               500G  200G  300G  40% /
hostname:/local           1T   20G  980G   2% /mnt/drive
```

How can I get "`hostname`" when given `/mnt/drive/file.txt`?

Answer (score 0):

The mount points can be parsed from the output of `mount -l`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import subprocess

mounts = {}    
for line in subprocess.check_output(['mount', '-l']).split('\n'):
    parts = line.split(' ')
    if len(parts) > 2:
        mounts[parts[2]] = parts[0]

print(mounts)
```

Then the path can be compared to the keys in the `mounts` dictionary, and the values can be further parsed to get the mount points.

source: https://askubuntu.com/a/189990/124703